# How to iterate over a range, get a specific word and paste it to an adjacent column until next key word is found in Google Sheets using scripts?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Impressed with how little I know, after hours trying to figure it out, I have to resort to you.

I'm thinking the process should be the following: Define keywords in an array; Iterate over the range; As the keyword is found, it starts counting until next ketword is found; Counter becomes the number of rows for that category; It starts over again with the next keyword found.

I started writing it, but I can't see multiple for loops here and I wonder how else it'd be:

```
function formatCells() {
  //Utilities.sleep(3000);

  //Formats Categories and cell colors
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const boqPipeworkSheet = ss.getSheetByName('BOQ Pipework');
  const boqPipeworkRng = boqPipeworkSheet.getRange(5, 1, boqPipeworkSheet.getLastRow(), 14);
  const boqPipeworkValues = boqPipeworkRng.getValues();
  let categoryToPaste = [];
  let categories = ['Copper pipework'];
  let counter = 0;
  for (let r = 0; r < boqPipeworkRng.length; r++) {
    let category = boqPipeworkRng[r][0];
    if (categories.indexOf(category) > -1) {
      categoryToPaste.push(category);
      counter++
    }
  }
}
```

Here's how the data is:
[image]

Here is a link to a file containing an example: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/138TD3eJU6GQtRj3uxXBJicn7pZyeXvAqU8lNcU01BDw/edit?usp=sharing

Thank you!

Comment: While a link to an spreadsheet might be helpful, question should be self-contained. Considering this please add into the question body some sample input data and the expected result. Also when adding code usually it's better to include a [mcve].

Comment: Just added it, @Rubén! Thank you!

Comment: In your script, only one value `Copper pipework` is set. It seems that this is "Category". But your sample image, several "Category" are shown and also several "Subcategory" are shown. In this case, how do you want to do in the array of `let categories = ['Copper pipework']`?

Comment: Hi, @Tanaike! I started testing it with ```Copper pipework``` but got lost through the rest of the process

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your goal, you want to retrieve the values by declaring all "Category" and "Subcategory" as an array. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Tanaike, the challenge is to get the categories and subcategories those rows are related to and list them in columns C and D. Controlling the iteration on where to start and finish for each category and subcategory is where I get lost. Arigato for helping!

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying of `the challenge is to get the categories and subcategories those rows are related to and list them in columns C and D` and your sample image, how about using the background colors of cells? By this, I thought that "Category" and "Subcategory" can be retrieved. Is this included in the direction you expect?

Comment: I guess it could work with the background color, @Tanaike!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to use formula.

For Categories, in F3

```
={"Category";ArrayFormula(lookup(row(A4:A),row(A4:A)/--REGEXMATCH(B4:B,"^[ ]{2}[A-Z].*"),B4:B))}
```

For Subcategories, in G3

```
={"Subcategory";ArrayFormula(if(REGEXMATCH(B4:B,"^[ ]{2}[A-Z].*"),"",lookup(row(A4:A),row(A4:A)/--REGEXMATCH(B4:B,"^[ ]{4}[A-Z].*"),B4:B)))}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! In case, Category begins with 2 spaces "  " and subcategory with 3. I've tried adjusting your solution to it, but without success so far. ```={"Category";ArrayFormula(lookup(row(A5:A),row(A5:A)/if(left(A5:A,3)<>" ",1,0),A5:A))}```

Comment: ok, I have updated my answer

Comment: Impressive! Formulas can get deep!!! Merci!